# sorl.thumbnail is not creating thumbnails in my views

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have installed sorl.thumbnail and added it to my installed_apps. 
In my view:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{%block title%}{{user.get_full_name}}{% endblock %}
{%block content%}
{%load thumbnail %}
    <h1>{{user.get_full_name}}</h1>
    <div class="profile-info">
        {% thumbnail user.profile.photo "180x180" crop="100%" as im %}
            <img src="{{im.url}}" class="user-detail">
        {% endthumbnail %}
    </div>
    {% with total_followers=user.followers.count %}
        <span class="count">
            {{total_followers}}
        </span>
            follower{{total_followers|pluralize}}
            <a href="#" data-id="user.id" data-action="{%if request.user in user.followers.all %}un{%endif%}follow" class="follow button">
                {%if request.user not in user.followers.all %}Follow{%else%}Unfollow{%endif%}
            </a>
    <div id="image-list">
        {%include 'images/image/list_ajax.html' with images=user.images_created.all %}
    </div>
    {% endwith %}   

{%endblock%}
```

However, the thumbnail tag creates nothing in view. am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing a border-radius attribute in your css. If you already have that and it's still not working, clear your browser cache.